# Passing data between controllers in angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In my angular app I have a product view/controller that has the common questions for product (SKU, Name, Description etc). I also have a dropdown field named ProductType that I will use to load a dynamic view/js/controller for questions that vary based on that product type. When the user saves the product I'll have a property on the base product model named ProductTypeConfig (as well as ProductType) that contains a json representation of the product type configuration and I want to pass all that to the server controller for persistence.

Has anyone seen this done before in Angular? Comments or clues as to how to go about this? I don't want to load all of js for every product type controller etc. ahead of time as this will potentially be plugable by the client as new product types are rolled out.

#### EDIT:

Ok, so I created a plunk to demonstrate what I'm trying to accomplish. I have the dynamic piece working well I think. At this point I just need to figure out how to grab the dynamic data in the saveProduct() function in the ProductController. When save is clicked, I need to somehow call a method on either the TypeAController or the TypeBController depending on which one is loaded. I was thinking that I could probably create a service that all the controllers would depend on and have it do the work. Is this something that is possible?

The plunk is located here http://plnkr.co/edit/6kQYKU

This is the main controller:

```
(function() {
  var app = angular.module('ProductApp', ['ngRoute']);

  app.config(function($httpProvider, $routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.
    when('/', {
      templateUrl: 'product.html',
      controller: 'ProductController'
    }).
    otherwise({
      redirectTo: '/'
    });

  });

  var ProductController = function($scope, $log, $routeParams, $location) {
    var saveProduct = function() {
      // how to get data from either TypeAController or TypeBController here when saved from ProductController
      $log.log('Product saved')
      $location.path('/');
    };

    $scope.saveProduct = saveProduct;

    // values
    $scope.ProductId = 1001;
    $scope.Name = 'Product 1001';
    $scope.Type = 'typea';

  };
  app.controller("ProductController", ProductController);


}());
```

And this is one of the dynamic views with it's controller:

```
<div ng-controller='TypeAController'>
<h1>Type A Settings</h1>
<fieldset>
  <div class="dnnFormItem">
    <label>Width:</label>
    <br />
    <input type="text" name="width" ng-model="Width" />
    <br />
    <label>Height:</label>
    <br />
    <input type="text" name="height" ng-model="Height" />
    <br />
  </div>
</fieldset>
</div>
<script>
  console.log('TypeA is loaded');
  var TypeAController = function($scope, $log) {

  };
  angular.module('ProductApp').controller("TypeAController", TypeAController);

</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up doing a simple factory to share an object between controllers as demonstrated in this plunk, http://plnkr.co/edit/6kQYKU. This also demonstrates loading a dynamic view based on a field in the parent view.

```
  var stateService = function() {
      'use strict';

      var state = {};

      return {
        state: state,
      };
  };

  app.factory('StateService', stateService);
```